# How to restrict server less lambda function

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, serverless

I implemented lambda function and it's working fine.Can I restrict user to access lambda function by using  I AM role? How?

Answer (score 0):

You brought up a good point. Here are things you need to understand about permissions on AWS with Lambda.

**What Lambda can do?**

This comes under resource-level permissions, create policies or roles and assign it to the lambda. Lambda will have access to those resources.

**What a user can do on a Lambda?**

This comes under User-Level permissions. As of this writing below screenshot shows the permissions you can control over the lambda. Create a Role and assign it to the user, it will take care of security accordingly.

[image: Lambda Policies]

Hope it helps.